# In Terraform how do I join a string during the Terraform Plan Phase?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I am having trouble creating a resource.  During the plan phase I get the error

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
>
> var.ENVIRONMENT is a string, known only after apply
>
> var.LOCATION_SHORTNAME is a string, known only after apply
>
> var.PLATFORM is a string, known only after apply
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "identifier_uris": list of string │
> required

Here is the resource I am working on:

```
  resource "azuread_application" "yellow" {
  display_name     = join("", ["app-yellow-",var.PLATFORM,"-",var.ENVIRONMENT, "-",var.LOCATION_SHORTNAME])
  identifier_uris  = join("", ["https://app-yellow-",var.PLATFORM,"-",var.ENVIRONMENT, "-",var.LOCATION_SHORTNAME, ".azurewebsites.net"])
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]


  web {
    redirect_uris = join("", ["https://app-yellow-",var.PLATFORM,"-",var.ENVIRONMENT, "-",var.LOCATION_SHORTNAME, ".azurewebsites.net"])

  }
}
```

It makes sense.  Its looking for a string, but that string is not built yet because it does not run until the Apply Phase.

I have tried playing with depends_on, but have not had much luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you defining the inputs for the variables? Also note the final error means that you should be passing a `list(string)` for that argument value, and not a `string`. You probably also will find it cleaner to interpolate strings instead of `join` on `list(string)`.

Comment: So I have a file called variables.tf.  In there I have 
`variable "ENVIRONEMENT" {
    type = string
}`

The values are coming from Azure DevOps Library.  For example I have a variable called TF_VAR_ENVIRONMENT with dev as its value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try providing an array for uris as below:

```
  resource "azuread_application" "yellow" {
  display_name     = join("", ["app-yellow-",var.PLATFORM,"-",var.ENVIRONMENT, "-",var.LOCATION_SHORTNAME])
  identifier_uris  = join("", ["https://app-yellow-",var.PLATFORM,"-",var.ENVIRONMENT, "-",var.LOCATION_SHORTNAME, ".azurewebsites.net"])
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]


  web {
    redirect_uris = [join("", ["https://app-yellow-",var.PLATFORM,"-",var.ENVIRONMENT, "-",var.LOCATION_SHORTNAME, ".azurewebsites.net"])]

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making some changes.  I created a variable called

```
variable "YELLOW_REDIRECT_URIS" {
    type = string
}
```

And then added the var in Azure DevOps

`TF_VAR_YELLOW_REDIRECT_URIS` with the value I needed instead of trying to build it on the fly.  It accomplishes the goal for now.